# How often does a mpu6050 gyro sonsor need calibration?

Tags: sensors, mpu6050, robotics, gyroscope, calibration

I want to use it in my real car for daily use to measure yaw angle when needed.

Is is ok to only calibrate it once at first then use it every day when driving without any problem? if not, how often should I recalibrate it?

Comment: Sorry for asking, but many 1st time posters get accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer mixed up. It depends on the manufacture.  But many accelerometers and gyroscopes work with only a small amount of calibration if any.  And I can not think of a good reason to calibrate them a second time.  A magnetometer needs calibration the 1st time and every time afterwards should conditions change.  And magnetometers do not work well near metal objects.  Like cars. (BTW, a MPU6050 has an accelerometer and gyroscope but no magnetometer.)

Answer (score 1):

Most accelerometers and gyroscopes need little if any calibration.  Consult the manufactures specification sheets.  If any calibration is made and correction values found, then it is assumed those values may be used in the future for the same accelerometer / gyroscope.

[This analog.com document](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/technical-articles/gyrocalibration_edn_eu_7_2010.pdf) goes into gyroscope calibration details.

Deriving the angle of the car (the "yaw") at any given moment will likely be problematic.  Errors from integrating the gyroscope's axis which is perpendicular to the ground will accumulate over time.  Which is the main problem when using [dead reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning).

Consider using a magnetometer & accelerometer along with the gyroscope in order to mitigate the accumulated errors from only using the gyroscope.

Comment: I just want it to find the 45 angle when parallel park. when car is fixed to adjacent car, reset it to zero then go reverse to reach 45 degree. I reset sensor's current position by a button as zero position.  Is it wrong? what is your idea?

Comment: The longer the interval of time over which a maneuver is tracked the more likely errors will creep into your calculations. You will have to be the judge as to how much error your application can tolerate and what is a reasonable amount of time for you to make the maneuver.  My ideas deal with longer car trips and integrating a tilt compass to aid in correcting any accumulated gyroscope errors. I don't think that is necessary for this case.

Comment: I don't want to use compass in my car anyway. because it needs calibration every time I want to parallel park. The time for reaching a 45 angle in parallel park is about 10 seconds or less. At that moment the sensor's work is finished. The sensor is going to be used once a day by average.

Comment: Excuse me, a micro question! Can I reset the sensor (x, y, z) to (0, 0, 0) logically using code (not calibrate)? because calibration takes much time.

Comment: Most gyroscopes are zero at rest and fluctuate when rotated.  It is normally up to the hosting processor to translate that into an angle.  Some gyroscopes can be written to to adjust / calibrate the gyroscope output.  But these values can be kept as part of the hosting processors program so that raw un-calibrated values are read from the gyroscope.